# How to return full substring from partial substring match in python as a list?

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, findall

I have different length strings which have to be checked for substrings which match patterns of "tion", "ex", "ph", "ost", "ast", "ist" ignoring the case and the position i.e. prefix/suffix/middle of word. The matching words have to be returned in a new list rather than the matching substring element alone. With the below code I can return a new list of matching substring element without the full matching word.

```
def latin_ish_words(text):
    import re
    pattern=re.compile(r"tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist")
    matches=pattern.findall(text)
    return matches
latin_ish_words("This functions as expected")
```

With the results as follows:`['tion', 'ex']`

I was wondering how I could return the whole word rather than the matching substring element into a newlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
pattern=re.compile(r"\w*?(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist)\w*")
pattern=re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]*?(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist)[a-zA-Z]*")
pattern=re.compile(r"[^\W\d_]*?(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist)[^\W\d_]*")
```

The regex (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V59Ctl/1)) matches

- `\w*?` - zero or  more but as few as possible word chars
- `(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist)` - one of the strings
- `\w*` - zero or  more but as many as possible word chars

The `[a-zA-Z]` part will match only ASCII letters, and `[^\W\d_]` will match any Unicode letters.

Mind the use of the non-capturing group with `re.findall`, as otherwise, the captured substrings will also get their way into the output list.

If you need to only match letter words, and you need to match them as whole words, add [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), `r"\b[a-zA-Z]*?(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist)[a-zA-Z]*\b"`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tsC0M9):

```py
import re
def latin_ish_words(text):
    import re
    pattern=re.compile(r"\w*?(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist)\w*")
    return pattern.findall(text)
 
print(latin_ish_words("This functions as expected"))
# => ['functions', 'expected']
```

Answer (score 0):

*ignoring the case*

```
pattern=re.compile(r"tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist")
matches=pattern.findall(text)
```

does not do that, consider following example

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r"tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist")
text = "SCREAMING TEXT"
print(pattern.findall(text))
```

output

```
[]
```

despite there should be `EX`, you should add `re.IGNORECASE` flag like so

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r"tion|ex|ph|ost|ast|ist", re.IGNORECASE)
text = "SCREAMING TEXT"
print(pattern.findall(text))
```

output

```
['EX']
```

Answer (score 0):

For a case insensitive match with whitspace boundaries you could use:

```
(?i)(?<!\S)\w*(?:tion|ex|ph|[oia]st)\w*(?!\S)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for a case insensitive match (Or use `re.I`)
- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\w*` Match optional word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `tion|ex|ph|[oia]st` Match either `tion` `ex` `php` or `ost` `ist` `ast` using a character class
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\w*` Match optional word characters
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OMvXDw/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1QYxvR)

```
def latin_ish_words(text):
    import re
    pattern = r"(?i)(?<!\S)\w*(?:tion|ex|ph|[oia]st)\w*(?!\S)"
    return re.findall(pattern, text)

print(latin_ish_words("This functions as expected"))
```

Output

```
['functions', 'expected']
```